# SCP copies files successfully, but files not visible in local computer

Tags: ssh, debian, scp

I SCP ed to copy files successfully, i.e. the transfer shows it's successful, but I don't see anything in my local folders.

The command:

```
scp name1@server1.edu:/file/*.* ~/Desktop/
```

I am running Debian, if that might be of some help.

Comment: It may be helpful if you show the command you use, how you know it is successful, and how you check for the files in your local folders.

Comment: How you scp ? put your command? how to specify your path on target?

Comment: I think you sent correctly, but didn't check correctly.

Comment: Please find the edited version of the question.

Comment: If you want to copy a directory (`name@server.edu:/file/.`), use `scp -r` for recursive copy. If `file` is really a file, then use `name@server.edu:/file` without the trailing `/.`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the SFTP home path.Your  successfully transferred files are copied by default to this path.Hope this will help you !